# Convert user query to SPARQL Query

Tags: sparql

I'm building a movie ontology for my class project. My problem is how do I integrate user entered query (Through provided web page) to SPARQL Query and get the list of answers from the database through the ontology.

I have some knowledge of mapping the ontology with my database. Please provide me a solution for this.
Thanks in advance.
(I'm using Protege with ontopro plugin for mapping)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you mean converting user queries to machine understandable queries, is not an easy task. This is a question in the domain of Question Answering (QA) and needs sophisticated work.

Three steps of building a QA system including question analysis, document (database) analysis and answer extraction. Each of these three, also consists of different tasks. For example, question analysis includes feature selection and extraction, building a classifier and evaluating it to get the Expected Answer Type (EAT).

But if you have a static format for your queries, then you can ask users to propose their queries in that format and then, you have an easier job of matching user queries to SPARQL queries and getting the answers. 
Personally, I think you should start from the point of having the SPARQL query or use a keyword-based interface instead of a text-based interface if you want to make your job easy as this method is suitable for small projects.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by user query? a text search? a faceted search? a mix? something else? For me, this is not clear and a bit of detail would help understanding.

Also an example would actually be ideal. Like the "user query" and the "sparql equivalent" if possible.

Comment: Sorry for the misguiding. User query is actually a text search. Let say user enters "movie directed by steven spielberg". So the equivalant SPARQL query will be like this. 

SELECT ?title ?link WHERE {
  ?film rdf:type movie:film ;
        foaf:page ?link ;
        dc:title ?title ;
 movie:director ?director.
  ?director movie:director_name ?nameDirector.
  FILTER ( REGEX(?nameDirector, "Steven Spielberg","i") 
           && REGEX(STR(?link), "^http://www.imdb.com/title", "i")
         )
  }ORDER BY ?title

 So I want to convert text search to SPARQL Query to get the result from my ontology.